# used to... with the number of times

Tags: grammar

I've read that 'used to' isn't used while we're saying how many times something happened in past.

So, we can say:

I visited him several times.

But we cannot say:

I used to visit him several times.

My question is, can we say this:

I used to visit him several times in a day/ month.

Actually, here the idea is of frequency in a single time i.e. month, day. Since the words 'day' and 'month' refer to an event, not the number of actions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are onto the right pattern here. If no time period is either specified or implied, you can't use "used to … X times". But if a time period is specified, you certainly can.

For example:

> I used to visit him several times a month; now I only visit once a month.

Or you could use your initial sentence "I used to visit him several times" as long as some span of time is implied.

> These days I only visit him once a month. I used to visit him several times.

Anecdotally, as a native speaker, when I first read "I used to visit him several times," I didn't even think it sounded wrong because I just automatically imagined a scenario where some time period would be implied.